# Reading a csv file with a list of elements into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have a CSV file in the following format:

```
index      A      B      C
ind1    [1,2,3][3,4,5][6,7,8]
ind2    [1,4,3,4,8][9,1,2,1,4][3,7,3,5,9]
ind3    [2,8][1,8][1,5]
```

where each cell (say A,ind1)has a list [1,2,3].
When I import this into a dataframe:

```
df=pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
```

I get a dataframe in the same format as the csv, however, the list in individual cell is imported as a string.

Say I index the first element of ind1 column A
`df.iloc[0]['A']` gives me `'['` instead of `1`

basically it is reading `[1,2,3]` as one long string instead of reading it as a list.

How do I convert the values in all the cells into list?

Comment: You've described your problem pretty clearly: your data file is *not* in CSV format, so `read_csv` isn't the right tool for you.  You need to research how to read lists in sequence.

Comment: Have you printed out the data frame?  I would expect that first data line to have 7 entries, denoted by those commas, rather than a single string.

Comment: the csv file is output from a different program which converts a dataframe into csv using `df.to_csv`. When I directly index the dataframe that generated the csv, I am able to access the list. But when I write it as a csv and read it again, the individual cells are considered as strings instead of lists

Comment: Let me guess: you're using `Pandas` data frames?  You have to read using the same (complementary) format you used to write it out.  If you wrote with a `pandas` method, then you need to read it with a `pandas` method.  You used a generic CSV reader -- and the file is *not* generic CSV.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interesting question. If you will use pandas i would use literal_eval to encode at first the list.

`import pandas as pd
 from ast import literal_eval
 df = pd.read_csv("filename.csv")`

Than you can use pandas applymap to apply the literal_eval function to every cell.

```
df[['A', 'B', 'C']] = df[['A', 'B', 'C']].applymap(literal_eval)
```

Now, you have extracted the list and you can react with them like a normal list.
e.g. this will give you from the first list the first element:

```
df.iloc[0]['A'][0]
```

I hope that will help you

Comment: You can also do `import ast; df=pd.read_csv('filename.csv', converters={"A": ast.literal_eval})`